# auto is not allowed here in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

```
void OrderBook::withdrawOrder( string& time){

  orders.erase(std::remove(orders.begin(), orders.end(),[&time](auto 
  order){ return order.timestamp == time && order.username == "simuser"; }),
  orders.end());
    
  
}
```

This is my code, auto before criteria is giving error "auto is now allowed here". What am I doing wrong.```

Comment: Because this requires C++14.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik How do i fix it?

Comment: -std=c++14 or -std=c++17 on the compile line.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong.

You are using `auto` for a lambda parameter in a language version where that's not allowed.

> How do i fix it?

Potential solutions:

- Upgrade your language standard to at least C++14, which is the language version where `auto` lambda parameters were introduced.
- Use an explicitly typed parameter, if only one argument type is needed.
- Use a named function class with a templated or overloaded function call operator instead of a lambda, if more than one argument type are needed.